Getting 'Unknown argument' and 'Cannot query field' errors when fetching OHLC and Volume data from BitQuery for a custom symbol on Jupiter DEX
I'm trying to retrieve OHLC and Volume data in a 4-hour timeframe from Jupiter DEX using BitQuery's GraphQL API for two trading pairs with the following contract addresses:

CzLSujWBLFsSjncfkh59rUFqvafWcY5tzedWJSuypump (Token Goatseus Maximus)
9JhFqCA21MoAXs2PTaeqNQp2XngPn1PgYr2rsEVCpump (Token Claude Opus)

Initially, I constructed the following GraphQL query:
{
  solana {
    dexTrades(
      options: {asc: "timeInterval.hour"}
      date: {since: "2024-10-13", till: "204-10-31"}
      exchangeName: {is: "Jupiter"}
      baseCurrency: {address: {is: "CzLSujWBLFsSjncfkh59rUFqvafWcY5tzedWJSuypump"}}
      quoteCurrency: {address: {is: "9JhFqCA21MoAXs2PTaeqNQp2XngPn1PgYr2rsEVCpump"}}
    ) {
      timeInterval {
        hour(count: 4)
      }
      baseCurrency {
        symbol
        address
      }
      quoteCurrency {
        symbol
        address
      }
      trades: count
      volume: tradeAmount(in: USD)
      high: quotePrice(calculate: maximum)
      low: quotePrice(calculate: minimum)
      open: quotePrice(calculate: open)
      close: quotePrice(calculate: close)
    }
  }
}

When I ran this query on BitQuery's GraphQL IDE, I received the following error:
Cannot query field "solana" on type "RootQuery".

I realized that I needed to use another endpoint for streaming Solana blockchain data, so I entered https://streaming.bitquery.io/eap in the URL textbox next to the Fork tab in the query editor. After updating the endpoint, I adjusted the query to match the new schema:

Changed solana to Solana
Changed dexTrades to DEXTrades

Here's the updated query:
{
  Solana {
    DEXTrades(
      options: {asc: "timeInterval.hour"}
      date: {since: "2024-10-13", till: "204-10-31"}
      exchangeName: {is: "Jupiter"}
      baseCurrency: {is: "CzLSujWBLFsSjncfkh59rUFqvafWcY5tzedWJSuypump"}
      quoteCurrency: {is: "9JhFqCA21MoAXs2PTaeqNQp2XngPn1PgYr2rsEVCpump"}
    ) {
      timeInterval {
        hour(count: 4)
      }
      baseCurrency {
        symbol
        address
      }
      quoteCurrency {
        symbol
        address
      }
      trades: count
      volume: tradeAmount(in: USD)
      high: quotePrice(calculate: maximum)
      low: quotePrice(calculate: minimum)
      open: quotePrice(calculate: open)
      close: quotePrice(calculate: close)
    }
  }
}

However, I am now encountering multiple errors:

On the arguments of DEXTrades:


Unknown argument "options" on field "Solana.DEXTrades".
Unknown argument "date" on field "Solana.DEXTrades".
Unknown argument "exchangeName" on field "Solana.DEXTrades".
Unknown argument "baseCurrency" on field "Solana.DEXTrades".
Unknown argument "quoteCurrency" on field "Solana.DEXTrades".


On the fields inside DEXTrades:


Cannot query field "timeInterval" on type "Solana_DEXTrade_Cube".
Cannot query field "baseCurrency" on type "Solana_DEXTrade_Cube".
Cannot query field "quoteCurrency" on type "Solana_DEXTrade_Cube".
Cannot query field "tradeAmount" on type "Solana_DEXTrade_Cube".
Cannot query field "quotePrice" on type "Solana_DEXTrade_Cube".

My Goal:
I want to retrieve the OHLC (Open, High, Low, Close) and Volume data in 4-hour intervals for the specified trading pair on Jupiter DEX, this data can be seen on this Jupiter link after setting GOAT as the baseCurrency and OPUS as the quoteCurrency


Note: When trying to display the Volume indicator in the chart, for some reason it is removed after doing so, but the Net Volume indicator works.

The data should include:

OHLC and Volume data for the specified token pair, OHLC data can be fetched just in the Quote Currency.
Volume should be fetched in both Quote Currency and USD (it must be converted).

Question(s)
How can I modify my GraphQL query to correctly retrieve the desired OHLC and Volume data from Jupiter DEX using BitQuery's streaming endpoint? What's the right schema or approach I should use to avoid these errors?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Additional info:

Environment: Using BitQuery's GraphQL IDE at https://streaming.bitquery.io/ide
Endpoint: https://streaming.bitquery.io/eap
Blockchain: Solana
DEX: Jupiter

